# Connect to server and get directories using WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, remote-server

I need some help, I want to build a windowsForm app which allows me connect to remote server with credentials and get the shared directories.

Already try this, but it throws me an unauthorized access exception when I use credentials different from those of my PC.

```
NetworkCredential netCredential = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);
CredentialCache netCache = new CredentialCache();
netCache.Add(@"\\" + server, port, "Basic", netCredential);
string[] theFolders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\" + server);
```

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Is the remote server in your network?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413(v=vs.85).aspx ; http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr.WNetAddConnection2

Comment: Yes, the server is in my network